# How to swap two nodes next to each other in a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am currently trying to swap two nodes in a circular doubly linked list. By current code:

```
private void swap(Card Card1, Card Card2) {

    if (Card1 == head) {
        head = Card2;
    } else if (Card2 == head) {
        head = Card1;
    } if (Card1 == tail) {
        tail = Card2;
    } else if (Card2 == tail) {
        tail = Card1;
    }

    // Swapping Card1 and Card2
    Card temp = Card1.next;
    Card1.next = Card2.next;
    Card2.next = temp;

    if (Card1.next != null) {
        Card1.next.prev = Card1;
    } if (Card2.next != null) {
        Card2.next.prev = Card2;
    }

    temp = Card1.prev;
    Card1.prev = Card2.prev;
    Card2.prev = temp;

    if (Card1.prev != null) {
        Card1.prev.next = Card1;
    } if (Card2.prev != null) {
        Card2.prev.next = Card2;
    }

    head.prev = tail;
    tail.next = head;
}
```

This code should swap between any two nodes in the linked list but for my application. I am just using it to swap with the next node.

```
public void moveCard(Card c, int p) {
       for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
          swap(c, c.next);
       }
}
```

Here I am using it to move a card across the list by p positions. Is this correct logic?

I Have been trying to debug this for so long and I cant find where it goes wrong. Any Ideas?

Comment: You code seems to imply that Card1 and Card2 are always next to each other in the list, is this correct?

Comment: Why are there `null` checks on `prev` and `next` members? They should never be `null` in a circular list. If they are `null` then the circular list is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `Card2` is `Card1.next` then the assignment `Card2.next = temp` will make `Card2` reference itself. This surely breaks the correct continuation of the swap.

The check for `null` references could be removed, as in a circular list these should *never* be `null`. I didn't see your `Node` class, but if you initialise those members to `null` there, then change it: make them self references instead, so you can guarantee that `prev` and `next` are **never** assigned `null`.

I would take a step back and extract both nodes via a separate `extract` function, and insert them again with a separate `insertBefore` function.

To avoid havoc, make sure that `Card2.next` is not `Card1` (so in opposite order). If this is the case repeat the call with the arguments switched, so that `Card1.next` is `Card2`. But there is still a special case to deal with: if these two cards are the only members of the list, there is no way to prevent that `Card2.next` is `Card1`, so that case should be dealt with separately: it is an easy case where only `head` and `tail` should reference the other node than they currently do.

There shouldn't be much code to set `tail`, as there is an invariant: `tail` is always `head.prev` in a non-empty list. So you can just make that assignment at the end.

And I would also use camelCase for your variables, so `card1` instead of `Card1`.

Here is the suggested code:

```
private void insertBefore(Card card, Card next) { // card is assumed not to be in list yet
    card.next = next;
    card.prev = next.prev;
    card.prev.next = card;
    card.next.prev = card;
}

private void extract(Card card) { // Does not modify its prev/next members
    card.next.prev = card.prev;
    card.prev.next = card.next;
}

private void swap(Card card1, Card card2) {
    // Deal with boundary cases:
    if (card1 == card2) return; // Nothing to do
    if (card2.next == card1) {
        if (card2.prev == card1) { // List has only 2 elements
            tail = head;
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        return swap(card2, card1);
    }
    // Here we are sure card2.next is not card1
    Card next2 = card2.next;
    extract(card2);
    extract(card1);
    insertBefore(card2, card1.next);
    insertBefore(card1, next2);
    // Fix head/tail references
    if (head == card1) head = card2;
    else if (head == card2) head = card1;
    tail = head.prev;
}
```